# Problem with gradient descent least squares code

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to use gradient descent on a data set. What I have written is

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Teacher/Downloads/data.csv')
X = data.iloc[:, 0]  # selects all data from first column in data
Y = data.iloc[:, 1]
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
n = len(X)

a = 0
b = 0
L = .001

for i in range(1000):
    y_predicted = a * X + b
    pd_a = (1 / n) * sum((y_predicted - Y) * X)
    pd_b = (1 / n) * sum(y_predicted - Y)
    a = a - L * pd_a
    b = b - L * pd_b
print(a, b)
plt.scatter(X, Y)
c, d = numpy.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
print(c, d)
plt.plot([min(X), max(X)], [a * x + b for x in [min(X), max(X)]], [c * x + d for x in [min(X), max(X)]])
plt.show()
```

If I instead define X and `Y = np.random.rand(20)`, then everything seems to work fine, so I the issue appears to be with the iput from csv.
However, the scatterplot for X and Y is still fine, even when I define them as the first and second column of my data set, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Edit: Here is an image of the scatterplot after defining X = data.iloc[:, 0]
Y = data.iloc[:, 1]

[image]

Here is an image of the plot and line at the end of the code.

[image]

The result of print(data.head()):

[image]

Edit: reading just one line of the csv:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added two images if it clarifies things. Clearly, the gradient descent algorithm does not produce the proper line. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the csv, I would do the below to troubleshoot why reading from the csv does not work;

> Assumption: there are 2 rows per line in csv, so we create X and Y as lists using the below for loop

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Teacher/Downloads/data.csv')
X, Y = [], []
for i in data:
  X.append(i.split()[0])
  Y.append(i.split()[1])
```

Comment: I get an Index error: list index out of range, for the Y.append line.

Comment: can you share the results of data.head() and len(data) ?  I want to see how this looks and the size

Comment: Just added as the third image. The result of len(data) is 99.

Comment: @user124910 thanks for sharing. Please print i before the append and share. know the structure and type of data elements can help knw exactly how to split and append this

Comment: @user124910 can we focus on resolving the source of X and Y ? You know looking at the data.head() I can see your x, y values are not highly correlated. So you are not expecting a perfect fit for your output. Until we get the input right lets not focus much on the line. Looking forward to the structure and type of 1 as you loop over the dataframe

Comment: It's just a sample data set. I ran the program just changing X and Y to random data lists, and it worked fine, so it makes me think that the code is right, but there's something wrong with defining X and Y as the the first and second column from the csv.

Comment: ok, I was expecting the real csv data not the random. So use pandas to read just one line of the csv and share it, also check the data type of the single line you read and confirm. Reason for asking this is if we know the structure of how you get the x,y values we can accurately split and append X or Y.

Comment: I've changed it to data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Teacher/Downloads/data.csv', nrows=1), to get the first row of data. The result of print(type(data)) is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.

Comment: OK you don't need to limit the number, you can print print data.head() for summary. What happens when you use the for loop to on the real csv data ? you mentioned you used the random data earlier